# MySQL inner join not returning results

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to inner join two tables to add a column to one of the tables.

Here are how the tables look

**Table1**

```
Name               year  
Dickerson, Molan   2015
```

**Table 2**

```
Person_ID Last_Name   First_Name
23        Dickerson   Molan
```

But, when I inner join via:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.name like CONCAT('%', table2.Last_Name, '%') 
AND table1.name like CONCAT('%', table2.First_Name, '%')
```

I get empty results. Why? The goal is add the `ID column` to **table1**

Comment: @GordonLinoff no, sorry. I'll edit. Was just trying to show that they're strings but, that should be inherent...

Comment: Are you sure you get empty results with exactly the data you've shown here? I can't: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d131a/1

Comment: @shree.pat18 Well the real tables have more entires but, some names like the one above aren't in the results while others are...

Comment: check Column Character Set and Collation of both columns used in the where clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html

Comment: @Omesh They have the same collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON (t1.name like CONCAT('%', trim(t2.Last_Name), '%') 
    AND t1.name like CONCAT('%', trim(t2.First_Name), '%') )
```

Comment: your data maybe wrong, show the result of query? or try again with trim           ON (t1.name like CONCAT('%', trim(t2.Last_Name), '%')

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.name like CONCAT('%', table2.Last_Name) 
AND table1.name like CONCAT(table2.First_Name, '%')
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The first query returned a little over a million rows with names being matched that aren't the same. Second query didn't work b/c of a syntax error.